# MVC FancyBox 2.1.5 not working with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fancybox, lightbox

I INCLUDE ALL (in header):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-css-transform.js"></script>
@*<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>*@
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-css-transform.js"></script>
```

In my Index view I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ChaseSymbolID').click(function () {
            $('#ChaseSymbolID').fancybox({
                    'height': 380,
                    'padding': 0,
                    'width': 700,
                    'type': 'iframe'
                });
        });
</script>
```

AFTER RUN I HAVE:

JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'fancybox'

(but normaly intellisense offers this option: .fancybox(a) ...)

I've just made the update to FancyBox 2.1.5 and jQuery 1.10, but since then FancyBox has stopped working. I tried with lightbox2 and it's working Ok, but i need fancybox to work.

Comment: can you show the rendered script tags from view source? what order they rendered?

Comment: upgrading? remove any reference to previous versions of fancybox. Also, you just need to bind `#ChaseSymbolID` to fancybox but not the `click` method. In any case, your script above will return an error since it's not properly closed

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complete fancybox library file `jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js` in the `Scripts/fancybox` folder then let the MVC to resolve the path for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js")"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to script execute in views?

Default MVC create layout with `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in the end.
You have to move it to `<head>` tag and it'll work.